# Basis for Tensor products/bilinear maps

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

[image]

What is the delta in the image? How do I check it is a basis? Why are $i$ and $k$ the same, and $j$ and $l$? Need some clarification.

Comment: It's the Kronecker delta, which seems to have occurred to you.

Comment: That is what I thought initially, but it is weirdly written. I have always known it to be $\delta_{ij}$

Comment: This construction is easier than it may look. Those particular maps allow you to control the values of the form on the basis elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $\delta$s stand for Kronecker's delta: $$\delta_{ij} = \delta_i^j = \begin{cases} 1, & \text{if } i=j \\ 0, &\text{if } i\neq j \end{cases} $$
I will prove that the $\{f_\gamma^{kl}\}$ form a basis for $L(E\otimes F,G)$, and you do the other one. Let $\lambda_\gamma^{kl}$ be scalars such that the finite combination is zero: $$\sum \lambda_\gamma^{kl} f_\gamma^{kl} = 0 $$

Evaluating both sides on $x_k \otimes y_l$ gives: $$\sum \lambda_\gamma^{kl} z_\gamma = 0 $$

Linear independence of the $z_\gamma$ finally gives $\lambda_\gamma^{kl} = 0$. So the set is linearly independent.

Now we check that it spans everything. Let $\xi \in L(E \otimes F,G)$. If $x_k\otimes y_l$ is an element of the basis of $E\otimes F$, then $\xi(x_k \otimes y_l)$ writes as a finite combination $$ \xi(x_k \otimes y_l) = \sum \lambda_\gamma^{kl} z_\gamma $$ for some scalars $\lambda_\gamma^{kl}$. I claim that: $$\xi = \sum \lambda_\gamma^{kl} f_\gamma^{kl}$$ To see this, we compute the right side at an arbitrary basis element $x_i \otimes y_j$ and see that it equals $\xi(x_i\otimes y_j)$.  We have:

$$\sum \lambda_\gamma^{kl} f_\gamma^{kl}(x_i \otimes y_j) = \sum \lambda_\gamma^{kl} \delta_i^k \delta_j^l z_\gamma = \sum \lambda_\gamma^{ij} z_\gamma = \xi(x_i \otimes y_j),$$as wanted.

Comment: I'll concede that I've been sloppy writing the summations (typing on the mobile!). If you have trouble understanding, please tell me and I'll write it neatly.

Comment: It is fine, would the other one be the same? I haven't really done tensor products so am not conformable with the notation

Comment: The other one is very similar, so I could've made either one here, but I chose the tensor one because of the notation. The point is that the tensor product sort of transforms bilinear maps in $(x,y)$ in linear maps on $x \otimes y$. Keep that in mind and you should be able to do it. For proving linear independence, write the combination equal to zero and evaluate both sides on a convenient pair. And to prove the spanning part, write the values of the bilinear map as combinations of the $z_\gamma$ and pick the coefficients as I've done here.

Comment: Thanks. But why is k and l needed? Are they not the same as i and j?

Comment: No. For example, $f_3^{12}(x_2\otimes y_2) = 0$ because  $i = 1 \neq 2 = k $, whence $\delta_1^2 = 0$, and $f_7^{34}(x_3\otimes y_4) = z_7$ because $i = k = 3$ and $l = j = 4$, whence $\delta_3^3 = \delta_4^4 = 1$. Try to write a few of them to get the hang of it. Using all indices $i,j,k,l$ is a way to say the values of a lot of maps in a lot of elements all at once.

Comment: Thanks again. What is the best way to find a basis? Of for example linear maps from $ X \times Y $ to $Z$

Comment: You can find a basis for $L(U,V)$ and apply the construction for $U = X\times Y$ and $V = Z $. You'll need to know how to find a basis for $X\times Y$ using bases for $X$ and $Y$, sure. The idea is to define maps from $U$ to $V$ that capture the values of a linear map in a basis. Say $\{u_i\}_{i=1}^n$ and $\{v_j\}_{j=1}^m$ are bases for $U$ and $V$. Define $T_{kl}(u_i) = \delta_i^l v_k$. Then $\{T_{kl}\}$ will work.

Comment: $X \times Y$ basis is $\{(x_i, 0), (0, y_j) \ | \ \text{for all values of} \ i, j\}$ so just sub that into the linear map you have defined?

Comment: Precisely. Everywhere you see a basis element of $U$, put an element of the basis for $X\times Y$ instead.

Comment: Is there any basis without using the delta? Because it doesn't seem intuitive

Comment: I'm pretty sure yes, although I can't think of any now. Think of the delta only as a shorcut to saying/writing "$1$ if $i=j$, $0$ if $i\neq j$", etc. Or else you'd write the definition of every map there as something like $$\begin{cases} \cdots \\ \cdots \end{cases},$$ much more cumbersome.

Comment: What if we removed the delta from both bases? Would the result still be a basis?

Comment: No, because we would be repeating maps on the set, and it would be linearly dependent (hence not a basis)

Comment: Could I have an example of a repeat? I can't think of any...

Comment: For example, $T_{kl} = T_{km}$ if $k\neq m $

Comment: +1 for doing this on mobile. I barely answer questions now since I don't really use my computer and it's a pain to write good answers on the phone.